# JSON Error when parsing "... has no method 'replace'"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, javascript-objects, fs

Let me preface this with the admission that I am a complete programming and javascript noob and that fact is the source of my trouble.

I'm trying to populate a large array of custom objects from a text file that I've saved to with json.stringify. When I grab the file contents and json.parse(them), I get the following error:

```
var backSlashRemoved = text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '@'
                            ^
TypeError: Object (contents of file) has no method 'replace'
```

The code that causes this error is:

```
fs.readFile('/savedcustomobjectarray', function (err, data) {
  var customobjectarray = json.parse(data);
});
```

I'm guessing I'm going about this all wrong. I saw some people mention serializers for this sort of thing, but I wanted to double check if that's what I needed (and maybe get some direction in how to use them in this context). It seems like the stringify output is fine, though, so I'm not sure why JSON can't just put humpty dumpty back together again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The text.replace line is in /vendor/commonjs-utils/lib/json-ext.js, not my code. I assumed this was part of JSON. Perhaps I am wrong? Is there a different way to parse my object array through JSON?

Comment: `.replace` can only be called on a String. Check whether text is a string or another object

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your regex?

Comment: @JohnP I'm not sure how to apply what you said. The text from the file is the stringified JSON file, and the text.replace isn't in my code but rather brought about from the json.parse(data) code.

Comment: @Drackir I'm sorry but my noobishness is coming through again. What part, exactly, is my regex?

Comment: @clixby the part inside the replace, would you please edit your question show us a sample of the data and explain the whole process

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I didn't write the text.replace code. It's in /vendor/commonjs-utils/lib/json-ext.js:75 so I assumed it was part of JSON that I was dealing with incorrectly. Would commenting out that line fix the problem without creating new ones?

Comment: If you're doing something like `text = JSON.parse(text);` that means you're calling `replace` on a JS object. Could you post the parsing code, and the code where you call the method that has the `replace`?

Comment: @JohnP I found a copy of my json-ext.js here: http://code.google.com/p/persevere-framework/source/browse/trunk/WEB-INF/narwhal/packages/commonjs-utils/lib/json-ext.js?r=675

Comment: @clixby, that's the framework, I don't think the error is there. The problem is not the `text.replace` itself but the fact that You're calling the `.parse()` method and passing it an object instead of a string.

Comment: @JohnP The problem was that I didn't know the data from the text file was considered an object. I changed the line to var customobjectarray = json.parse(String(data)); and it seems to be working. I don't know stackoverflow etiquette, so I'm not sure if I should post the fix as an answer or let you do it.

Comment: @clixby usually you should let the person who helped post. But go ahead and post and accept your answer. Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 5):

`fs.readFile` takes 2 or 3 arguments, when passing only the filename and a callback, then your callback function will get the following two arguments `(err, data)` where `data` is a raw [buffer](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/buffers.html).

So the right way to do it would be:

```
fs.readFile('/savedcustomobjectarray', function (err, data) {
  var customobjectarray = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8'));
});
```

`data.toString` takes the encoding as the first argument.

Alternitavley you could specify the encoding as the second argument to the `fs.readFile` and have it pass a string to the callback:

```
fs.readFile('/savedcustomobjectarray', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var customobjectarray = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Node API [docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/all.html) is your best friend!