# has no method 'replace' jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following js code which is erroing in the console and i'm not too sure of what i'm doing wrong. Basically i'm trying to get a list of fields so i can do some calcs on.

```
var LabourItems = {
    rate: null,
    hours: null,
    total: null,
    init: function(object) {
        var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
        var hours =$(object).children('.hours').first();
        total = rate * hours;
        updateTotal(object,total);
    },
    updateTotal: function(object,  total) {
        $(object).children('.total').first().attr('value', total)
    }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').live(function() {
    var labourItems;

    jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
        labourItems.push(LabourItems.init(value));
    });

});
```

Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    var labourItems;

   jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
       labourItems.push(LabourItems.init(value));
   });

} has no method 'replace'
```

Comment: there were similar questions asked: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9385767/944681), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5900713/944681) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8970482/944681)

Comment: i see, so where do i put the .join in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`live` needs an event type eg. `click`.

it's treating the function as the event string and it's getting hella confused.

```
$('.hours').live(function() { /*... your code ...*/})    // wrong
```

needs to be:

```
$('.hours').live("click", function() { /*... your code ...*/})    // works
```

Comment: that did the trick, not sure why my question got downvoted, it is not the same as the one linked.

Comment: will do asking me to do it another 2 minutes, also now it says UpdateTotal is not defined when i click on the field linked to it.

Comment: That means your `live` now works and you have another problem. Try troubleshooting it for a while before you post a question.